# Error: segmentation fault en C

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente código que me da como error *segmentation fault*.

Agradecería ayuda para saber qué estoy haciendo mal:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cargaVector(int v[], int *n);
void ordenarVector(int v[], int n);
void mostrarVector(int v[], int n);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    
    int v[50], n;

    cargaVector(v, &n);

    ordenarVector(v, n);

    mostrarVector(v, n);

    return 0;
}

void cargaVector(int v[], int *n){

    printf("Cuantos elementos desea ingresar: "); scanf("%d", &*n);
    for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++)
    {
        printf("Ingrese elemeto %d: ", i); scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
    
}

void ordenarVector(int v[], int n){
    int aux;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; i < n; j++)
        {
            if (v[i]>v[j])
            {
                aux= v[i];
                v[i]= v[j];
                v[j]= aux;
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

void mostrarVector(int v[], int n){

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){

        printf("%d\n", v[i]);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Tienes un error en uno de los bucles: `for (int j = i; i < n; j++)` debería ser `for (int j = i; j < n; j++)`. Al estar comparándolo por el valor de `i`, que no aumenta de valor en ese bucle, la condición nunca se cumplirá y entrarás en un bucle infinito que aumentará `j` hasta que accedas a una zona de memoria que te provoque ese error.

Comment: muchas gracias! no lo pude ver, era eso!

Comment: regarding:  `scanf("%d", &*n);`  the limit for 'n' is the declared size of v[].  Specifically 50.  However, there is nothing in the posted code to limit the value in 'n' to 50 or less

Comment: la construcción &*n es confusa e innecesaria
si pusiera directamente n le daría lo mismo no haberlo hecho no es la causa del error, pero es bueno que los programas sean lo más claro posibles.
Es también confuso usar un mismo nombre de variable para dos cosas que significan cosas distintas podría haber puesto int * dn (abreviatura de dirección de n) y le hubiera sid o natural en la lectura direccionarla hacia dn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un error en uno de los bucles:

```
for (int j = i; i < n; j++)
```

Debería ser:

```
for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
```

Al estar comparándolo por el valor de `i`, que no aumenta de valor en ese bucle, la condición nunca se cumplirá y entrarás en un bucle infinito que aumentará `j` hasta que accedas a una zona de memoria que te provoque ese error.

La función debería quedar así:

```
void ordenarVector(int v[], int n){
    int aux;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        /* Aquí cambiamos i < n por j < n */
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            if (v[i] > v[j]) {
                aux = v[i];
                v[i]= v[j];
                v[j]= aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Además, podrías simplificar la línea del `scanf("%d", &*n)` por `scanf("%d", n)`. O, mejor aún, hacer que la función devuelva el número de elementos como valor de retorno.

Comment: Muchas gracias! funciono a la perfeccion.